# Error with an import module jnius while using imagej in python

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies, imagej, pyjnius

I am trying to connect a headless imageJ library to my python application. Unfortunately, the dependency error list goes on endless and I am now stuck at an import error involving the import of a java wrapper called jnius.

So far I have installed: wheel, imagej, cython, imglyb, pyjnius modules using an updated pip. Since the "Unable to determine JDK_HOME" was triggered in between, I followed the obvious rules of updating environment Variable list to my paths (both user and system). In between, pyjnius reported `"Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"` and I installed the same (a hefty 5.63 GB) and additionally the "VCForPython27".

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('JAVA_HOME'))
print(os.environ.get('JDK_HOME'))
```

both the command gives me the following output:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\server
```

Now I can import imageJ in my code, but when I try to use its first function

```
ij = imagej.init('C:\\Users\\Documents\\ImageJ_Fiji\ImageJ-win64.exe')
```

I get the following error associated with `import scyjava` as: `"Unable to import scyjava dependency jnius."` and when I try to run `pip install jnius --user` I get the same old error: "Unable to determine JDK_HOME'" which seems confusing since I had successfully installed `pyjnius` and a `pip install scyjava --user` gives me an output that all requirements are satisfied.

I am no longer using a conda environment (since it got me very confusing), my python version is 3.7.2 and my OS is windows 10. The editor I use is PyCharm. I have installed the latest JDK and JRE from oracle website.

Referance: [Jnius installation bug, "Unable to determine JDK_HOME"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067834/jnius-installation-bug-unable-to-determine-jdk-home)
[jnius 1.1 import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970732/jnius-1-1-import-error)

Answer (score 2):

Installation of pyimagej has been discussed on the image.sc forum, e.g. [in this topic](https://forum.image.sc/t/cannot-find-imagej-module-after-installing-pyimagej-with-conda/23190?u=imagejan).

Also, there are currently a few open issues/PRs in `scyjava` ([#5](https://github.com/scijava/scyjava/issues/5) and [#7](https://github.com/scijava/scyjava/pull/7)) and `pyimagej` ([#21](https://github.com/imagej/pyimagej/issues/21#issuecomment-445494049)).

As far as I understand, the recommended way to install `imagej` in Python is using conda, as activating the environment with `conda activate imagej` will set the required environment variables for the dependencies.

For further questions, I recommend asking on the [image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc).

Answer (score 0):

There are working condition need to be satisfied, along with installing [Java (JDK)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jdk8-downloads.html), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and python packages Cython, pyjnius, scyjava, imglyb, and pyimagej.

1) Environment variable `JAVA_HOME` point to the JDK directory.

In your case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2`. I think the redundancy (*/bin, JDK_HOME etc.) should not harm.

2) Environment variable `Path` contains directory of JDK binaries and Maven binaries.

e.g. for Java it is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin`. When installing or compiling pyjnius, you are likely need them.

3) Hava `pyjnius.jar` located somewhere and set environment variable `PYJNIUS_JAR` to point to it, so that `scyjava` can find it.

The error "pyjnius JAR not found" and "Unable to import scyjava dependency jnius." correspond to this step. So you are likely missing the (undocumented) step (3).

Step (3) is currently automatically done if you are using `conda`. Otherwise you need to download `pyjnius.jar` separately somewhere. See discussion [here](https://forum.image.sc/t/how-do-i-install-pyimagej/23189/3). Note that without `pyjnius.jar` the python module `jnius` will still functioning, but somehow `scyjava` still need that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors when I installed the imagej package with `pip install imagej`. Using `pip install pyimagej` solved the issue.